# Is functional $\int_0^a \left( (u')^2 - u^2 \right) {\rm d} x$ convex?

Tags: real-analysis, optimization, convex-optimization, calculus-of-variations, minimal-surfaces

<sub>I posted a question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4335787) and I think I solved the point two of the question. Is my approach right?</sub>

---

Give that the functional

$$I[u] = \int_0^a \left( (u')^2 - u^2 \right) {\rm d} x$$

is homogenous, i.e., $I[\lambda u]= \lambda^2 I[u]$ for all $u \in X$ and $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$, where

$$X = \left\{ u \in C^2([0,a]) \mid u(0)=u(a)=0 \right\}$$

I want to prove that $v$ is weak local minimizer iff $v$ is a global minimizer. I am planing to show that $I[u]$ is convex functional so the result be immediate.

---

**My proof for convexity**

Let $\lambda \in [0,1]$ and $u,v \in X$, then

\begin{align}
I[\lambda u + (1-\lambda)v]&= I[\lambda u] + I[(1-\lambda)v]\\
& = \lambda^2 I[u] + (1-\lambda)^2 I[v]\\
&\leq \lambda I[u] + (1-\lambda) I[v].
\end{align}

Thus, $I[u]$ is convex in $X$, the every local minimizer is global minimizer.

Comment: You need $I[\lambda u+(1-\lambda) v]$ on the left , not  $I[\lambda u+(1-\lambda) u]$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thanks, it was typo. I will edit it now.

Comment: How did you end up with the first equality??? $I$ is not additive.

Comment: @copper.hat I assumed it is possible because it is just integration.

Comment: @copper.hat could you help me with this one?

Comment: Perhaps you can view $u$ as an $a$-periodic function and expand in a Fourier series? The map from a function to its Fourier coefficients is linear.

Comment: I would suspect the answer to this depends on $a$.

Comment: @copper.hat I solved this point using another argument.

Comment: @SelfLearner How did you do that?

Comment: @copper.hat could you please go to the link "here" in the post, or this link -https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4335787/what-about-wirtingers-inequality-when-a-pi, I posted my latest updates.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $a \in (0,\pi]$ then $I$ is convex.

To apply the Wirtinger's inequality, we need $u$ to have zero average over. Extend $u$ to $[-a,0]$ so that it is odd, then $\int_{-a}^a u(x) dx = 0$. I will assume that $u$ is defined on $[-a,a]$ subsequently and any Fourier coefficients are over this domain.

Let $\hat{u}_k$ denote the Fourier coefficients. Note that the maps $u \mapsto \hat{u}_k$ are (real) linear. Since the map $(x,y) \mapsto x^2+y^2$ is convex, we see that the maps $u \mapsto |\hat{u}_k|^2$ are convex. Note that $\hat{u}_0 = 0$.

Since $u \in C^2[0,a]$, we see that (the extended) $u,u' \in L^2[-a,a]$. We have $\hat{u'}_k = -i k {\pi \over a} \hat{u}_k$, and Parseval gives
${1 \over 2a}\int_{-a}^a u^2 = \sum_k |\hat{u}_k|^2$, ${1 \over 2a}\int_{-a}^a (u')^2 = \sum_k (k {\pi \over a})^2|\hat{u}_k|^2$.

In particular, $I(u) = a \sum_k ((k {\pi \over a})^2-1)|\hat{u}_k|^2 = a \sum_{|k| \ge 1} ((k {\pi \over a})^2-1)|\hat{u}_k|^2$.

Since the non negative sum of convex functions is convex, we see that $I$ is convex.

Now suppose $\pi < a$ and let $u(x) = \sin({\pi \over a} x)$, we can compute $\int u^2 = {a \over 2}$ and $\int (u')^2 = ({\pi \over a})^2 {a \over 2}$ to get
$I(u) = (({\pi \over a})^2-1) {a \over 2} < 0$.

Since $I(-u) = I(u) < 0$ and $I({1 \over 2} (u+(-u))) = 0$, we see that $I$ is not convex.

Comment: could you tell me how did you get $\int u^2 =\frac 1 2$ ?

Comment: There was a missing factor of $a$, but the integration is elementary.

Comment: Thank. I just wanted to make sure, i knew it was typo.